# Populate readonly nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using ModelViewSets and I have nested serializer for these models.

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    
    id          = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email       = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    is_staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**update**
How can I autocomplete a newly created profile with 1:1 relation to User that is sending the request?

So, you are registering on a website, now you are a user but you want to have profile, some bio so you are setting up your profile for that

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('password', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'groups', 'user_permissions')

class ProfileSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    place = PlaceSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

**viewsets**

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    get_queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data = serializer.data
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

As you can see I'm using 'drf-writable-nested' and it works okay but I can't figure it out how to automatically connect profile to user on new profile creation.

Comment: Do you want to set some default user with each profile everytime?

Comment: Can you share your ViewSets?

Comment: I've edited my post with viewsets. @haox_illued users need to be the one who is sending the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically connect a newly created profile to the user sending the request, you can modify the `create` method in your `ProfileViewSet`. Here's one way to do it:

```py
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # Set the user to the requesting user
            serializer.save(user=request.user)
            data = serializer.data
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Note that this assumes that you are using token authentication or some other form of authentication that identifies the user making the request. If not, you will need to modify this code accordingly to identify the user in some other way.

Answer (score 2):

You will have [`CurrentUserDefault`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) if you want to use read_only field.

```
user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    read_only=True, 
    default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)
```

Or you can omit user and pass it while saving the serializer like this:
`serializer.save(user=request.user)`

Comment: To make this work in function that is calling the serializer we need to pass `context={'request': request} ` like this `ExampleSerializer(product, context={'request': request}) `